# Error: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime

Tags: vb.net

I am getting error `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` parameters describe an un-representable `DateTime`, as the below code

```
 FristDate = New Date(Year(frm.dtpInMonth.Value), Month(frm.dtpInMonth.Value), "-1")
```

[image]

Comment: day can not be -1 ?????

Comment: When have you ever seen a date with a day of -1?  Perhaps if you actually explained what you were trying to achieve, we could explain how to achieve it.

Comment: This kind of thing works in Excel, but .NET is a little more strict. You have to work with valid dates and do computation from there.